# Can we get conversation history from Azure Web PubSub

Tags: azure, websocket, chat, publish-subscribe, azure-web-pubsub

I am developing a chat window using Can we get conversation history from Azure Web PubSub. Is there a way i can get the convesation history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/resource-faq#where-does-my-data-reside), the Azure Web PubSub service works as a data processor service and does not store customer messages. Therefore, you need to leverage other Azure services to store the conversation history. There is a Chatr application built by Ben Coleman which may be a good reference for you. You could start from this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/build-serveless-real-time-chat-application-with-web-pubsub-and/ba-p/2433211).